How to use cytoscape for nutrigenomics
I am a doctor, want to use cytoscape for nutrigenomics. Where to start for nutrigenomics. What needs to be the input for analysing different food. Where to get data for analysing different food. What are the steps. Please guide me.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I'm sorry but this is just too broad a question for this site. It is like asking "how can I use a pencil to write a novel". Sure, it is possible that cytoscape might be useful when working in nutrigenomics, but we cannot tell you what to do. You need to tell us what you are trying to do. Cytoscape is simply a network visualizer, with some plugins to analyze the network. It isn't a magic bullet. You need to figure out what biological questions you want to answer and then take it from there.
